# video plays in wrong collection view cell

Tags: firebase, video, swift3, uicollectionview, avplayer

I have a collection view that displays a video in each cell. It also contains a play button and an image which is displayed before the video is played. When I scroll up and down it theres no problem, but when I play a video it shows in the right cell but sometimes it also displays in another cell when I scroll down. I've tried using DispatchQueue(not sure if its the right thing to do) and that doesn't work so I'm stuck for ideas. I have another similar collection view that shows just images and it works perfectly but I'm having issues with this collection view because it displays videos instead. I've searched other questions but I can't find the answer I need to solve this issue. Help would much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Collection view controller

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: homePostCellId, for: indexPath) as! videoListCollectionViewCell

     cell.photoImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: posts[indexPath.item].imageUrl!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: “placeholder-image.png"))

     let tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(playVideo))


    return cell
            }
        }
```

collection view Cell

```
    class videoListCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     var post: videoPost?

    lazy var playButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let image = UIImage(named: "playButton7")
            button.tintColor = UIColor.white
            button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState())

            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePlay), for: .touchUpInside)

            return button
        }()

        lazy var asset: AVURLAsset = {

            let videoUrlString = self.post?.videoUrl
            let url = URL(string: videoUrlString!)
            var asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url!)
            asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

            return asset
        }()

        var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
        var player: AVPlayer?
        var observer:Any!

        func handlePlay() {

// The video has been download already to the document directory
            let filename = self.post?.postID
            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(filename!)?.path
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let RealURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {

                player = AVPlayer(url: RealURL as URL)
                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                playerLayer?.frame = photoImageView.bounds
                photoImageView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)  
                player?.play()
                playButton.isHidden = true

                print("Playing from saved disk")

           NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem)

            } else {
// The video hasn't been downloaded so it's loading from the URL

            if let videoUrlString = post?.videoUrl, let url = URL(string: videoUrlString) {
                player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                playerLayer?.frame = photoImageView.bounds
                photoImageView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)

                player?.play()
                activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
                playButton.isHidden = true

                print("Attempting to play video")

                self.observer = self.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(1, 600), queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                    [weak self] time in

                    if self?.player?.currentItem?.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay {

                        if (self?.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp) != nil {
                            self?.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()                           
                        }
                    }
                }

                 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem)
                }
            }
        }

        func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification){
            print("Video Stopped”)
                self.player?.pause()
                playButton.isHidden = false

            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

            let filename = self.post?.postID
            let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last!

            let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename!)
            exporter?.outputURL = archiveURL
            exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4

            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(filename!)?.path
            let fileManager = FileManager.default

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {

            } else {
                exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {

                    print(exporter?.status.rawValue)
                    print(exporter?.error)
                })           
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your `playVideo` function which you are calling on tap gesture?

Comment: the playVideo function is in the collection view cell. It is the `func handlePlay()`@ViniApp. Sorry I need to remove the tap function from the main view controller because it's not how I access the play button

Comment: I've updated `func handlePlay()` just to make it bit easier to understand @ViniApp

Comment: @ViniApp are able to help me in anyway please?